# Adding Code Snippet in PentaHo kettle User defined java Class

Tags: kettle

I had written some custom code using java . I want to add the code to the User defined java class in Kettle in the code snippets section. Is there a way to add the custom code snippets in the Classes and code fragment in UDJC so that it can be reusable.
Thanks.

Comment: If I understand your question right, it sounds like what you may want to do is put some code in a jar and drop it in the lib-ext directory. I do this with some libraries that aren't part of Kettle that I want to use in code steps.

Comment: Thanks Gordon .I can explain little more on my previous question. I had written some custom code like the date formatter in UDJC. If I will bee able to add the same in the code snippet provided in the left panel than I can reuse the same. I want to add my code fragment in the left pane so that I can built up a library which will enhance reusability.

Comment: Ah, not sure about that; never used the left panel myself so i don't even begin to know how to add things to it

Answer (score 0):

For the moment there is no ability to add code snippets using ui at runtime. You can submit issue with [pentaho jira](http://jira.pentaho.com/) if you want this functionality. Or just as workaround you can edit codeSnippits.xml (situated under lib/kettle-ui-*.jar/org/pentaho/di/ui/trans/steps/userdefinedjavaclass/) and re-zip this file back to the jar.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend going down this path.
The reason is very simple, UDJC in PDI is [Janino](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home), a rather minified (but super fast) Java compiler, and I quote the [Pentaho wiki](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/User+Defined+Java+Class) for User Defined Java Class:

> Not 100% Java... The first thing to know is that Janino and as a
>   consequence this step doesn't need the complete Java class...  the
>   most apparent limitation is the absence of generics

What happened if we'd been able to add code snippets on the fly? Probably not good things.

However, and this is very useful, consider wrapping your code in a `JAR` package as suggested in the comments, include it in the `lib-ext` folder of your PDI environment and import it to User Defined Java Classes at will. IMHO, this is the right way.

I hope this helps a bit.